# Differentiate between the first request (authentication) and subsequent requests (also authentication)

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, token, basic-authentication

Using basic authentication I do this in my authentication handler:

```
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var authHeader = request.Headers.Authorization;
    if (authHeader == null || authHeader.Scheme != BasicScheme)
    {
        return CreateUnauthorizedResponse();
    }

    // Now authenticate the user with his name+pw

    // Return Auth token to user

}
```

Every time that means the first request or all subsequent requents the user request will go through the above SendAsnyc method. How should I differentiate in the above method wether the user want to authenticate himself (having username+password) the first time or authenticate himself (having the server generated auth token) all further times?

Comment: What _“server generated auth token”_ are you talking about? There is no such thing in HTTP _Basic_ Auth.

Comment: I know... but how do you authenticate a subsequent request after the login form? Store the user+pass on client side and send it for each request? hopefully not.

Comment: That’s how every browser does it … if you don’t like that, don’t use basic, but digest auth.

Comment: @CBroe ...only as long as the browser window is open then the credentials are resent with the http request. When the browser is closed and reopened the user does not want to login again therefore is the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options.

(1) Assuming that the token that is sent back from the server after successful authentication of username/password is sent in the `Authorization` header for subsequent requests (in a different scheme), rearrange your logic so that you look for basic scheme in authorization header and if present, authenticate and send back the token. If authz header with basic scheme is not present but your scheme or bearer scheme (whatever that is) is present, assume it is token and authenticate. If authz header is not present or if credentials in basic scheme is invalid or the token in the other scheme is invalid, send 401.

(2) Change the message handler so that it only does basic scheme authentication. If header is absent or invalid credentials or present, it just will not set the correct principal in `request.GetRequestContext().Principal` but does not send back 401. Introduce another message handler that will perform the authentication of token. This handler sets the correct principal only when the token is present in the request and token is valid. Again, this handler does not send back 401. Finally, apply `Authorize` filter at action method, controller or even globally. Filter will set the response status to 401, if an authenticated identity is not established by both message handlers.

I prefer the second one because the handlers have single responsibility of authentication. BTW, it is generally not recommended to use message handler to do authentication. The identity you establish here will be reverted back, once the execution goes back to IIS pipeline (assuming you use IIS).

Comment: I have found this sample code: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/630986/Cross-Platform-Authentication-With-ASP-NET-Web-API The author leaves that comment:"  //Just exclude the users controllers from need to provide valid token, so they could authenticate
" This was the missing piece in my head Badri. I wonder that you did not mention that approach (see register method). You wrote:" it just will not set the correct principal in request.GetRequestContext().Principal but does not send back 401" This makes no sense to me there must be a grammar?

Comment: Your approach to let the Filter return a 401 seems new to me never heard of that but interesting! It is generally not recommended to use message handler to do auth ??? But everyone is doing it and all samples show it ;-) seriously why not? You mean the identity/Principal will be deleted when the response starts ? And yes I use IIS.

Comment: On the topic of message handler, establish identity in message handler and look at IIS logs. It will not log the user because the identity reverts back. Look at the section "HTTP Message Handlers for Authentication" in http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api. Yes, every one is doing it and even my book Pro ASP.NET Web API security extensively uses message handler but if you are happy to have your security mechanism isolated to only Web API pipeline, message handler is okay. If web-hosting, consider using HTTP module or OWIN middleware.

Comment: As you did the most detailed description (but similar approach to Darrel, you have the solution. Btw. I run now Owin in a windows service with topshelf ;-)

Comment: About your option 2) "Finally, apply Authorize filter at action method, controller or even globally. Filter will set the response status to 401, if an authenticated identity is not established by both message handlers." This is even advised by Microsoft BUT how are you able to return an individual error message telling what the cause of the 401 is to the user? I think that will not work.

Comment: On the other side I must say when a 401 occurs (token invalid, client ip in token different, userId in token does not exist, etc...) in the context of a single page application (SPA) then there is either a program failure or someone is using fiddler and trying my ressource url`s. Should I return than the error message to the hacker? nah... but if its a program failure yes... What do you think Badri?

Comment: You don't typically tell what is wrong and what causes 401 to the client. You can however log and stuff but you simply return 401 to the client. Look at creating a custom authorize filter if you want to add anything on top of oob authorize.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the authorization scheme to differentiate.  When the user is sending a username/password then use the "basic" auth scheme.  When sending a token, use the "bearer" auth scheme.

Comment: I would prefer this method: http://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/message-handlers-scoped-per-route-in-asp-net-web-api/ Only plug the AuthHandler on the routes which is not the authenticate route. Shown here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/630986/Cross-Platform-Authentication-With-ASP-NET-Web-API

Comment: @Pascal The only issue I see with that approach is that if you share a link to a protected resource then the recipient is going to get a 401 and www-authenticate: bearer.  How do they know how to authenticate themselves and get a bearer token to be able to access the resource?  You would need to do a redirect to a resource that has the basic scheme and then redirect them back to the protected resource once they have the bearer token.

Comment: @Pascal By supporting both auth schemes on all resources then the bearer token just becomes a performance enhancing mechanism.

Comment: To your first comment: For my project everyone has his own account with own data. Sharing a link would not make sense. Because by manipulating the URL you get can others data which I have anyway to forbide... AND the link I pasted was just a sample for messageHandler per route etc... :-) A But thanks for your concern.

Comment: To your 2nd comment: Is this positively meant? Not sure I understand you correctly.

Comment: @Pascal When doing hypermedia being able to bookmark links, even to your own data can be useful. YMMV.  Regarding the second comment, yes, it was supposed to sound more positive than it did :-).  But it was an over simplification on my part.

Comment: As my client will be a SPA the client offers links/stateful UI to bookmark which is a separate thing from hypermedia and links. At least thats my assumption :-)

Comment: Again... when I return the 401 + www-authenticate I supress the auth dialog from the browser and show my own dialog. The use who recieved the link can anyway be only a customer and they HAVE a username+password so all is fine ;-)